# PHP regex match valid salary including symbol(s)

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate an input to match a salary or a salary range - the issue is that the user can enter a number of possible values.

For example, below is valid:

```
2000
2,000
2000.00
2,000.00

2000 - 4000
2,000-4,000
2,000.00-4,000.00
$2,000.00-$4,000.00
£2,000.00-£4,000.00
```

Initially we set out to allow everything except for letters but that would allow something like 2!000 which would not be valid

At the moment we have gotten:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d|\d,\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$/', $i)) {
   return true;
}
```

That does work for the first 4 examples but it allows things like 2a000 which is not valid - is there a way to list everything the string cannot contain (letters and symbols for example except for currency, period and comma) but still then do a pattern match so we can validate numbers for example?

Comment: I'd just strip out everything that's not a digit, dot, or dash and then validate what's left over.

Comment: I agree with Alex, you should dictate that the user can input digits only or digits separated by a single hyphen with no spaces. (There are "sliders" for this sort of thing.)  To capture their preferred currency, add another input/select field.  Otherwise you are going to have ambiguous salary expectations or arduous parsing to do.  By asking for data in its raw-est/essential parts, you can simply store and output the data in a fashion that is consistently formatted and in the style of your choosing.

Comment: Question shows examples in 2 currencies. I assume it may expect input in any currency. Some currencies have different separators, so accepting only numbers won’t work

Answer (score 4):

You might capture `$` or `£` in a group and then for consistency use a backreference to match the same symbol in the second part (which is optional).

To shorten the pattern a bit, you could use a [subroutine](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines) `(?2)` to repeat matching the digits in capture group 2.

```
^([$£]?)((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)\b(?:\.\d{2})?)(?:\h*-\h*\1(?2))?$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[$£]?` Optionally match `$` or `£`
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` Match 1-3 digits and repeat 0+ times matching `,` and 3 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `\b` Word boundary
  - `(?:\.\d{2})?` Optionally match a dot and 2 digits
- `)` Close group
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\h*-\h*\1` Match `-` between 0+ horizontal whitespace chars, followed by a backreference to what is captured in group 1 (optional `$` or `£`)
  - `(?2)` Repeat the pattern in **group 2** to match the digits
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yr25M4/1)

Comment: The use of the back references is pretty sweet.  This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a hyphen -, it indicates that you have range. To keep it simple I would explode() on hyphen and validate each part in a loop with 
$numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
var_dump( $numberFormatter->formatCurrency(1234.56789, "USD" ) );

If the formatter is able to return a string, it’s an indication that input is valid.

This would work even if salary is submitted instead of range.

Answer (score -1):

This one is quite strict so that all your entries from second group pass and none of the first group.

```
^[$£]?\d,?000(\.00)?([ -]+[$£]?\d,?000(\.00)?)?$
```

You can do something much more benevolent too. Such as replace the `[$£]` by `\D` to allow arbitrary currencies etc.

[Check it out](https://regex101.com/r/RfMYnd/3)

Comment: This doesn't come close to working.  For example it won't match $2,000.

Comment: Oh, was it supposed to match both lists from the example? Very simple modification (see the edit).